# ansible-galaxy - specify version range to install

Tags: ansible, ansible-galaxy

I am trying to install an Ansible Galaxy collection, but I need to force an older revision. [According to the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#installing-an-older-version-of-a-collection), I tried to perform installation the following ways:

```
$ ansible-galaxy collection install 'weareinteractive.ufw:>=1.10.0,<2.0.0'
Process install dependency map
ERROR! Failed to find collection weareinteractive.ufw:>=1.10.0,<2.0.0
$ ansible-galaxy collection install 'weareinteractive.ufw:<2.0.0'
Process install dependency map
ERROR! Failed to find collection weareinteractive.ufw:<2.0.0
```

I globally get the same kind of error when trying to do the same from this `requirements.yml`:

```
---
- name: weareinteractive.ufw
  version: '>=1.8.0,<2.0.0'
```

Running the command

```
$ ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
- downloading role 'ufw', owned by weareinteractive
[WARNING]: - weareinteractive.ufw was NOT installed successfully: - the specified version (>=1.8.0,<2.0.0) of weareinteractive.ufw was not found in the list of available versions ([{'id': 141713, 'url': '', 'related': {}, 'summary_fields': {}, 'created':
'2020-11-25T18:52:30.171540Z', 'modified': '2020-11-25T18:52:30.171568Z', 'name': '2.0.1', 'version': '2.0.1', 'commit_date': '2020-11-25T10:51:53-05:00', 'commit_sha': '30b1fdc8f5440e865d3fbeb83894941bf70739c7', 'download_url':
'https://github.com/weareinteractive/ansible-ufw/archive/2.0.1.tar.gz', 'active': None}, {'id': 76043, 'url': '', 'related': {}, 'summary_fields': {}, 'created': '2018-10-04T14:07:47.602784Z', 'modified': '2018-10-04T14:07:47.602810Z', 'name': '1.8.0', 'version':
'1.8.0', 'commit_date': '2018-10-04T10:05:07-04:00', 'commit_sha': 'ae776a7dc255ba5dc679cedee32129ba22c0e797', 'download_url': 'https://github.com/weareinteractive/ansible-ufw/archive/1.8.0.tar.gz', 'active': None}, .....]).
ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
```

What am I missing?

Edit: I'm using ansible / ansible-galaxy 2.9.16 but I expect a solution that will still works with ansible 2.10

Comment: What version of ansible-galaxy are you using?

Comment: ansible-galaxy 2.9.16

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the front page of the repository of the **role** you are trying to install:

> Ansible weareinteractive.ufw role

<sup>*Source: https://github.com/weareinteractive/ansible-ufw#ansible-weareinteractiveufw-role*</sup>

It is a role and not a collection.

Although the two syntaxes might lookalike, they actually don't totally have the same syntax.
For a role, first, you don't install them via

```sh
ansible-galaxy collection install some-collection
```

Obviously, but via:

```sh
ansible-galaxy install some-role
```

---

***Note:*** this is confirmed by both their GitHub page and their Ansible Galaxy page, that advise you to install the role via

```sh
ansible-galaxy install weareinteractive.ufw
```

<sup>*Sources: https://galaxy.ansible.com/weareinteractive/ufw
and https://github.com/weareinteractive/ansible-ufw*</sup>

---

Then, the version pinning differs too. On a role you have to specify a version, not a version range:

> When the Galaxy server imports a role, it imports any git tags matching the [Semantic Version](https://semver.org/) format as versions. In turn, you can download a specific version of a role by specifying one of the imported tags.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#installing-a-specific-version-of-a-role*</sup>

So you'll have to base yourself on the git tags of their repo, e.g.

```sh
ansible-galaxy install weareinteractive.ufw,v1.10.0
```

And the *requirement.yml* also [differs a bit](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/galaxy/user_guide.html#installing-multiple-roles-from-a-file), where you also have to give a specific verison.

```yaml
- name: weareinteractive.ufw
  version: v1.10.0
```

Comment: Crystal clear thanks. It looks like i totally missed the notion of collextion in Ansible. I will come back to the doc and learn the difference between a collection and a role